# How to open specific screen after tapping on notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, android-notifications

Currently when user receives a notification when the flutter app is minimized, and taps on notification, it redirects the user towards `screen A` every time. But I want the user to land on let's say `screen C` via deeplink which is created manually. Also, if user minimizes the app from any screen, tapping on notification takes user towards that screen. But irrespective of from where user minimizes the app or when app is in background, tapping on notification should redirect user towards `screen C` always. I haven't implemented notifications earlier, so this is my first time dealing with this issue, so looking for help in this regard.  Notification class code below:

```
companion object {

    const val CHAT_REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1775
    const val CHAT_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.com.CHAT_CHANNEL_ID"
    const val CHAT_CHANNEL_NAME = "Demo Notifications"

    fun showChatNotification(context: Context, userName: String?, body: String?) {

        createChatNotificationChannel(context);

        val chatIntent = Intent();
        val deeplink = generateDeepLink(userName);
        chatIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        chatIntent.setData(Uri.parse(deeplink));
        val chatPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, chatIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val notification: Notification

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            notification = Notification.Builder(context, CHAT_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(chatPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_app_icon))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .build()
        } else {
            notification = Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(chatPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.app_icon))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(chatVibrationPattern)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentText(body)
                .build()
        }
        val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.notify(CHAT_REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    fun generateDeepLink(userId: String?): String {
        return "https://demo.page.link/?link=https://demo.com/chat?user=$userId&apn=com.example.com&efr=1";
    }

    private fun createChatNotificationChannel(context: Context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(CHAT_CHANNEL_ID)

            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHAT_CHANNEL_ID, CHAT_CHANNEL_NAME, importance)
            notificationChannel.description = "Message"
            notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using android emulators (6.0).

Answer (score 0):

@Dk15 You are doing right job what you have to do for the specific redirection send an event in your data from server like , 
while creating notification send an event like JOB_ACCEPTED,
so you can check on your on create 
 `if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)` 
 then redirect to switch statement and check which event you have received and then redirect user where ever you want to 
`switch (getIntent().getStringExtra("EVENT_TYPE")){
 Match your case here and redirect user in your case to SCREEN C
case "JOB_ACCEPTED":
          OPEN SCREEN C;
break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found that you have mention activity which you wants to open.

> val resultIntent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)

Follow [this](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_8_Notifications_Kotlin_Tutorial) step by step and you will get your answer.

or you can
Try [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     /**Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app**/
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext , SomeOtherActivity.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
            0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
}
```